# In sinon how do you spy on a module imported via "* as" when there are no functions

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, sinon, spy

I'm trying to spy on the marked package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked).

I imported in my code like this

```
import * as renderMarkdown from 'marked';
```

and use it like this

```
renderMarkdown(readme)
```

So how can I spy on it using sinon? Normally I spy on a imported method like this

```
import * as someImport from '../xxx'

...

const spy = sinon.spy(someImport, 'methodName');

...

sinon.assert.callCount(spy, 1);
spy.restore();
```

But in this case I don't have a "methodName" that I can use in the spy. Can anyone tell me how I can spy on this in my test to make sure it is called?

I tried

```
const spy = sinon.spy(someImport);
```

But the test errors and the method someImport is never called

```
AssertError: expected marked to be called once but was called 0 times
```

Comment: do you use jest ? from what I see, even in pure js it won't be possible easily to spy it (You'll need proxyquire or rewire for it)

Comment: No, it must be sinon